# Typed racket, changing a single component of a list

Tags: list, recursion, racket, typed-racket

Is there a way to change a single value of a list, called by list-ref, to a different value in typed Racket?

Like:  (Change (list-ref (list 1 2 2) 0) 4)
Would output: (list 4 2 2)

```
(: duck : (Listof Integer) -> (Listof Integer))
(define (duck n)
  (match n
    [' () ' ()]
    [(cons x r)
     (cond
       [(= x (list-ref n 1))
        (cons 4 (duck r))]
       [else (cons x (duck r))])]))
```

I wrote this recursive function in an attempt to do so, but it doesn't work. My logic is as follows: If x is (list-ref n 1) then change x to 4.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[`list-set`](http://mirror.racket-lang.org/releases/6.2.1/doc/unstable/list.html#%28def._%28%28lib._unstable%2Flist..rkt%29._list-set%29%29) from unstable/list does what you want:

```
#lang typed/racket/base
(require/typed unstable/list
               [list-set (All (a) (Listof a) Natural a -> (Listof a))])
(list-set (list 1 2 2) 0 4)
; '(4 2 2)
```

**Update:**

The latest version of racket now provides [`list-set`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._list-set%29%29) from `typed/racket`:

```
#lang typed/racket
(list-set (list 1 2 2) 0 4)
```

Or if you wanted to use `typed/racket/base`:

```
#lang typed/racket/base
(require racket/list)
(list-set (list 1 2 2) 0 4)
```